# Javascript substr with exceptions

Tags: javascript

I ask for help.
Can I connect the var urls like Test1 and Test2? Maybe with or ||? So that I can do without the many else if codes?

`<p id="demo">Test1</p>`

```
<script>
var urls1 = 'Test1';
var urls2 = 'Test2';
var urls3 = 'Test3';


if (document.getElementById('demo').textContent == urls1)
{
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Ihrer Region"; 
} 

else if (document.getElementById('demo').textContent == urls2)
{
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Ihrer Region"; 
}

else if (document.getElementById('demo').textContent == urls3)
{
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Ihrer Region"; 
}

else

{
var str1 = document.getElementById("demo").textContent;  
var str2 = str1.substr(0, str1.length-2);
            document.getElementById("demo").textContent = str2;    
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not just the `if` and `elses`. You code is so repeating, don't duplicate code!

Also, don't create vars with numbers suffix `urls1`, `urls2`... is just a list of URLs (or better saying, an array).

If you'll use the `document.getElementById('demo').textContent` multiple times, store this in a variable.

Read the official documentation, so you are able to know all the methods that you can use.

It sounds better?

```js
var urls = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];
var demo = document.getElementById('demo').textContent;

demo = urls.includes(demo) ? "Ihrer Region" : demo.substr(0, demo.length - 2);
```

Comment: Great! Many Thanks. I still have a lot to learn, but with such good help it's also fun!